# How to add a connection to RKEntityMapping when it is contained in the same JSON

Tags: ios, restkit

I'm trying to map a JSON response to instances of `NSManagedObject`, but i don't understand how to set the relationship/connection correctly.

My classes are:

```
@interface CloudObject : NSManagedObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CloudFolder *parent;
@end

@interface CloudFolder : CloudObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *children;
@end

@interface CloudFile : CloudObject
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * mimeType;
@end
```

JSON is something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Folder1", 
    "is_dir": true,
    "contents": [
        { "name": "Folder2", "is_dir": true }
        { "name": "File1", "is_dir": false, "mime_type": "audio/mpeg" }
    ]
}
```

I use `RKDynamicMapping` to map the response (root object):

```
RKEntityMapping *fileMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CloudFile" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[fileMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name", @"mime_type": @"mimeType"}];
RKEntityMapping *folderMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:@"CloudFolder" inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[folderMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name"}];
RKDynamicMapping *objectMapping = [[RKDynamicMapping alloc] init];
[objectMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"is_dir" expectedValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] objectMapping:fileMapping]];
[objectMapping addMatcher:[RKObjectMappingMatcher matcherWithKeyPath:@"is_dir" expectedValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] objectMapping:folderMapping]];
```

But how can I now setup the relationship/connection to `@"contents"` (which should be `RKDynamicMapping` too) and children/parent? (Folders contained in 'contents' do NOT have an 'contents'-attribute)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the RestKit documentation for dynamic mappings : [Dynamic Object Mapping](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-Mapping#dynamic-object-mapping).

According to the documentation, it looks like you should add this line, after creating your dynamic mapping `objectMapping`:

```
[folderMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contents" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:objectMapping]];
```

You specify the `"contents"` property as being mapped with your dynamic mapping. Also, you don't need to worry about the inner folders not having a `"contents"` field. If `"contents"` doesn't exist, RestKit should just ignore it gracefully, and your `NSSet *children` property will be automatically set to `nil` for that object.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Strange that I didn't read this article yet. But I think in my case it should be `[folderMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"contents" toKeyPath:@"children" withMapping:objectMapping]];`

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right! I'll edit my post. Glad I could help!